# Button with Image inside NavigationView scales incorrectly

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar, swift5, navigationview

When I use as system image everything works fine, but I have a png image of size 512x512 and I want to make it fit inside a navigationBarItem. The image just takes over almost all the screen with the following code:

```
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        Text("Main")            
            .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(action: {
                    print("button pressed")

                })
                {
                    Image("menu")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
        )
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GeometryReader` gives you the area designated by the parent. I found that the designated space is quite small but if you triple it, it fits well.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavItemImage: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            Text("Main")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title").font(.largeTitle), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    GeometryReader{geo in
                        Button(action: {
                            print("button pressed")
                        })
                        {
                            Image("menu")
                                .renderingMode(.original)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 3, height: geo.size.height * 3, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                    }
            )
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }

    }
}
```